# Eclipse CDT preprocessor get statement under condition

Tags: c, eclipse, c-preprocessor, eclipse-cdt, preprocessor

**To build a Eclipse plugin upon Eclipse CDT(NOT developing CXX using CDT)**, by using the API provided by Eclipse CDT, for the following code snippet, in Eclipse CDT, we can detect the ifdef statement(See IASTPressorIfStatement), but how can we obtain the statements under this ifdef directive. Specifically, in this example, we want to get the code "#include ". Or is there any other tools could do this?

```
#ifdef HAVE_SYS_PRCTL_H
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#endif
```

For example, in the code snippet, we want to get statements within the structure <#ifdef ...,#endif>. The return should be "#include".

For a normal case, let have the code snippet like:

```
#ifdef  condition
 statement A;
 statement B;
 .....
 statement Z;
#endif
```

I want to get the statement A, statement B,... and statement Z.*Note in the preprocessor statement, like IASTPreprocessorIfdefStatement, we can extract the macro name but not the statements I mentioned.

Comment: Have a google search for *eclipse cdt ast* and you will find lots of information, including some presentations to get you started.

Comment: By searching the CDT ast, especially IASTPreprocessorStatement for preprocessor-related statement, in some sub interfaces, like IASTPreprocessorIfdefStatement, you can extract the macro information, but you cannot get the information as I mentioned in the problem

Comment: Sorry that my previous comment tried to send you back to the beginning, I incorrectly assumed that you were asking about how to use the AST as you did not show us what you have done. I am not sure the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the region inside an `#ifdef` block need not contain complete declarations (or indeed complete AST nodes of any kind). For example, consider:

```
int i = 
#ifdef FOO
    42
#else
    43
#endif
    ;
```

This is valid code, but it does not make sense to ask for the declarations contained in the `#ifdef` or `#else` branches, because neither contains a complete declaration.

My best suggestion is to use an `ASTVisitor` to traverse the AST, and compare the offset and length of nodes you're interested in to the offset and length of the preprocessor statements. (Offsets and lengths of nodes can be obtained via `IASTNode.getFileLocation()`.) If the AST node is contained entirely within, say, an `#ifdef` and an `#else`, you know it's inside that branch. If the AST node overlaps the boundary of a preprocessor branch, you're in a situation like my example above, and it's up to you what you want to do with it.